# How can I run ad tags

Tags: javascript, php, iframe, adsense, ads

I am creating a pay-per click site.

Here I have advertisers and publisher.

I am running ads through a JavaScript code by creating iframe tag.

Now my client needs ad tag feature he wants to run other Google AdSense code along with our advertisers ads inside our publishers sites.

Now the problem is Google AdSense code won't work inside iframe tag.

Is there any solution for this?

This is the sample code which we are generating for publishers:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var val1 ="xxx";
var val2 ="yyy";
</script>
<script src="http://www.example.com/my.js"></script>
```

Here is the sample code for my JavaScript (**my.js**)

```
ifrm = document.createElement("IFRAME");
ifrm.setAttribute("src", "myadgeneratingcode.php?val1="+val1+"&val2="+val2);
ifrm.setAttribute("scrolling",  "no");
ifrm.style.width = wid+"px";
ifrm.style.height = hgt+"px";
ifrm.style.border = "none";
ifrm.style.clear = "both";
ifrm.style.position = "relative";
document.body.appendChild(ifrm);
```

And inside **myadgeneratingcode.php**

I am `selecting ads from database according to category, keywords` and displaying the ads and generating ads

**Is there any other method other than iframe to run my ads?**

Answer (score 0):

Here is the best and simple solution in php which i used in my website.

Instead of ad1.txt, ad2.txt..ad5.txt, Replace it with your google ads.

```
<?php 
$result_random = rand(1,10); 
if($result_random <= 2){ 
require ('ad1.php');
} 
else if($result_random <= 4){ 
require ('ad2.php');
}
else if($result_random <= 6){ 
require ('ad3.php');
}
else if($result_random <= 8){ 
require ('ad4.php');
}
else { 
require ('ad5.php');
} 
?>
```

Here is my Code with Screenshot http://php.sysaxiom.com/ad_management.php

Comment: i am accessing myadgeneratingcode.php through IFRAME, Thats the problem

Comment: You don't need to put the youradgeneratingcode.php through iframe. I guess it won't work. Put your google ad code into the ad.php and use my technique. Because i use it for most of my clients. So that i will generate different ad with high view rate.

Comment: here is the sample code which we are delivering to our publisher. By running this code we need to randomly  display ads from our site or google adsense ads `<script type="text/javascript">
var val1 ="xxx";
var val2 ="yyy";
</script>
<script src="http://www.mydomain.com/my.js"></script>`

Comment: I do understand. The only difference i did it in php, you did in js.

Comment: in side my php i do the same but my question is how to access php file from a javascript code without using `iframe`

Comment: Just do this inside your javascript. <script><?php echo require('ad.php')?></script>